# Is the Tenshinhan's Shin Kikoho technique, a triangle or square?

Tags: dragon-ball

When Tenshinhan prepares to launch the shin kikoho, he puts his hands in the form of a triangle.

[image: Oh snap~]

However, the attack ends up in the form of a square according to the destroyed area.

[image: OOOOOH SCHANP!!!]

Does anyone have a good explanation for this?

**EDIT**

Thanks for everyone, I've checked the manga chapters, and it seems that he puts his hands in a diamond shape, apparently, there was a mistake when making it into anime

Comment: I've added images, i think your talking about this right as i've only seen the original dub and i think your talking about Tian's Neo Tri-Beam

Comment: The second image sure looks like triangle to me.

Comment: @TendouKishi right side of Tian's hip you see the bottom right corner of the hole so you can visualize the edge that's under Tian, it's a perfect Rectange

Comment: Well, is there the after the technique image? I mean the resulting hole in the ground. It'd be much more clear if there is.

Comment: @Memor-X thanks, yes that's what I was talking about

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The attack leaves a square hole due to the way he holds his hands. When he fires the attack normally he places his hand in a diamond shape and zooms into his target. the attack then is shot and forms the square shape.

[image]

[image]

as you can see that his hands put together form more of a diamond shape and when he fires the attack it rotates and makes the square.

later in the series He changes the way his hands are placed and over laps the thumbs and make a triangle shape with is hands instead of the diamond shape.

it is stated on [Ultra DragonBall wiki](http://ultradragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Tri-Beam)

> Interestingly, this technique leaves a square hole in the ground, instead of a triangle.

Answer (score 8):

Though he put his hand in the form of triangle, the hole is in square/rectangular form. The answer is quite scientific. A [Reuleaux triangle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reuleaux_triangle) can be rotated to create a square shape. This [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L5AzbDJ7KYI) and this [site](http://io9.com/5829336/the-triangle-that-makes-rectangular-holes) explain it in more detail.

Tenshinhan's hand shape is similar to the Reuleaux triangle. Due to its shape, while it rotates, its cutting edge cut the hole in a shape of square which is shown in the gif below.

[image: Animation]

Comment: rather than only give a link, you should tell us what did they say and explain them.

Comment: @ShinobuOshino I posted anonymous edit with explanation. Before it'll get reviewed, see http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/20/Rouleaux_triangle_Animation.gif

Comment: i think this much explanation will be enough. describing principle and how it works may make the answer very long.

Comment: What is the source for your quote?

Comment: i removed quote